# Change anchor link in pop-up window based on clicked link in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, each

I'm currently helping to build a forum and we want to be able to warn users when they click links that will take them to an external site. At the moment, my code opens the pop-up window and will take the user to their designated link as expected.

However, if I were to click a different external link on the page, while the pop-up appears, clicking the redirect button pushes me to the first link I clicked.

How do I get it do that my code picks up the link that was clicked and uses that instead?

Here's the code I'm using so far. It's just a snippet from it.

```
$(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
      if (this.hostname != location.hostname) {
        let URL = $(item).attr("href");
        $(".modal").show();
        $('#redirectButton').click(function() {
          open(URL, '_blank');
        });
```

Comment: Making your button an anchor (as it should be for navigation) resolves this problem, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't remove the previous click handler it opens the previous link. Just remove the previous click handler first with `.off('click')`:

```
$(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
      if (this.hostname != location.hostname) {
        let URL = $(item).attr("href");
        $(".modal").show();
        $('#redirectButton').off('click').click(function() {
          open(URL, '_blank');
        });
```